# Getting Object doesn't support property or method 'entries' error even when I am adding polyfill

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, internet-explorer, polyfills

I am trying to load my web application on IE11 with the following `browserslist` configuration in package.json

```
"browserslist": {
 "production": [
   ">0.2%",
   "not dead",
   "not op_mini all"
 ],
 "development": [
   ">0.1%",
   "not dead",
   "not op_mini all"
 ]
}
```

and with the following statements at the beginning of `src/index.tsx`

```
import 'react-app-polyfill/ie11';
import 'react-app-polyfill/stable';
```

But I get an error saying `SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'entries'`. To overcome this I read the SO post at [Object doesn't support property or method 'entries'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42446062/object-doesnt-support-property-or-method-entries) but no good.

I tried installing `yarn add core-js` but when I try to do `import 'core-js/es7/object';` the build fails saying the module does not exist. What should I do here? What is it that I am missing?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210837/discussion-on-question-by-amanda-getting-object-doesnt-support-property-or-meth).

Answer (score 1):

> I tried installing yarn add core-js but when I try to do import
>   'core-js/es7/object'; the build fails saying the module does not
>   exist. What should I do here? What is it that I am missing?

Perhaps the issue is related to the core-js version. In my react application, it using core-js@3.0.1 version, it doesn't contain the es7 folder, and if I using the Object.entries() method, it works well in IE11 (not add polyfill, perhaps it already add the object reference).

[image]

Besides, I also checked my another application, it using the core-js 2.6.1 version, and we can see the core-js folder contain es7 package, you could also check the core-js version:

[image]

Try to refer [this link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/core-js?activeTab=versions) to update core-js version:

Besides, you could also add the following script in the header of Index.html. It also works well in IE11 browser.

```
    <script>
    if (!Object.entries) {
      Object.entries = function( obj ){
        var ownProps = Object.keys( obj ),
            i = ownProps.length,
            resArray = new Array(i); // preallocate the Array
        while (i--)
          resArray[i] = [ownProps[i], obj[ownProps[i]]];

        return resArray;
      };
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: I added `import "core-js/es/object";` at the top of `index.tsx` but still see the error. I am at `"core-js": "^3.6.4",`

Comment: How about the second method (add the JavaScript script in the header of Index.html), whether it works?