# Angular cli 15 and browserslist are targeting the incorrect ECMAScript version

Tags: angular, angular-cli, browserslist

I'm attempting to build an Angular 15 app using Angular CLI targeting ES6 (we need to support Chrome version 79).

The .browserslistrc file is as follows

```
> 0.5%
last 2 versions
Firefox ESR
Chrome >= 79
not dead
not IE 9-11
not kaios 2.5
not op_mini all
```

Yet the output .js files of the build use the null coalescing operator (??) which was added in ES2020 so it is not targeting ES6 as it should be. I get no warnings in the build that ES6 is not supported, which I do get if I attempt to target ES5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Browserlist does not determine what ES version your Typescript is compiled to. This is governed by the target ES version in your `tsconfig`.

```
// .browserlistrc:
> 0.5%
last 2 versions
Firefox ESR
Chrome >= 79
not dead
not IE 9-11
not kaios 2.5
not op_mini all

// .ts
console.log(null ?? 2);

// .js
console.log(null ?? 2); // tsconfig target >= es2020
console.log(false ? 0 : 2); // tsconfig target = es2019
```

Browserlist is for providing compatibility such as identifying applicable polyfills and build time targeting for other packages.

[What is the significance of browserslist in package.json created by create-react-app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55510405/what-is-the-significance-of-browserslist-in-package-json-created-by-create-react)

---

*"I get no warnings in the build that ES6 is not supported, which I do get if I attempt to target ES5."*

Angular 15 does not support ES5 any more which is why you get warnings. Support for that died with Angular 13 along with support for IE11.

https://blog.angular.io/angular-v13-is-now-available-cce66f7bc296